# Oracle SQL order by expresion

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to sort something by an expression and for some reason it won't work unless I have that expression as a selection :

```
    select distinct p.stuff
    from p.places 
    join otherPLACE
    order by cos(sin(to_number(p.nr_matricol)));
```

But I keep getting this error

> ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

If I write it like this

```
select distinct 
    p.stuff,
    cos(sin(to_number(p.nr_matricol)))
from p.places 
join otherPLACE 
order by cos(sin(to_number(p.nr_matricol)));
```

it works but I don't want to have that column printed.

Is there a way I can make this work ?

Comment: The DBMS doesn't know what `nr_matricol` you are refering to, as you have aggregated rows with `DISTINCT`, with each original row having their own `nr_matricol`. But `DISTINCT` itself is often a sign for a poorly written query. Seeing you select from places only, do you need to join? Maybe an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause would be better, Maybe even avoiding duplication that you must get rid of with `DISTINCT` then. Something like this might work: `select * from places p where p.x in (select op.y from otherplace op) order by ... `).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `order by` takes place after the `select distinct`.  The only values available are those in the `select`.  A typical approach would be aggregation.

Something like this:

```
select p.stuff
from places p join
     otherPLACE op
     on . . .
group by p.stuff
order by cos(sin(to_number(max(p.nr_matricol))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap into inline view

```
SELECT a FROM
    (select distinct p.stuff a, cos(sin(to_number(p.nr_matricol))) b
     from p.places 
          join otherPLACE) T
ORDER BY b;
```

**NOTE:** I hope your code was pseudo-code. Because you-re having Cartesian join, unless you specifying columns